# Using jQuery to strip out width and height tags on elements?

Tags: jquery, removeclass

The title is just my thought on how to do something, not necessarily, "the way", here is the situation.

I'm using the following to embedd nice square thumbnails from my Flickr feed into my site.

```
<div id="flickr_badge_wrapper" class="group">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flickr.com/badge_code_v2.gne?show_name=1&count=6&display=latest&size=s&layout=x&source=user&user=57701525%40N08"></script>
</div><!-- end flickr_badge-wrapper -->
```

Works just fine. Only the markup it generates (see below) contains a width="75" height="75". This is causing havoc because it's a fluid layout and I don't have a known height. I have figured out all the CSS... it works when I delete height from the img tag (tested in Firebug). Now I just need a way to get rid of that height attribute, after the Flickr feed has loaded.

```
<div id="flickr_badge_wrapper" class="group">
<script type="text/javascript" src="blah blah"></script>
  <div class="flickr_badge_image" id="flickr_badge_image1">
  <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/57701525@N08/5635787388/">
  <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5110/5635787388_ee1c039ba2_s.jpg" alt="A photo on Flickr" title=" " height="75" width="75"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Would love an idea with jQuery!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that they are all within `<div class="flickr_badge_image">`

```
$('div.flickr_badge_image img').removeAttr('width').removeAttr('height');
```

If you have control of the source though, it'd be much better to do this server side. Just in case JavaScript were turned off or to avoid any flash of content issues.

Comment: You sweet man. *Hug/High-Five/Fist-bumb*. And no I unfortunately don't see a way to do server side. But, perhaps you can answer another question. I cannot put the <script> tag from the beginning of my sample anywhere other than where on the page I want the feed to appear. But this is total BS because if Flickr is slow that day the rest of the page after doesn't load.. at least not until it does. Could I wrap it in something and then use some jQuery to keep it from running until the document is loaded? Here it is "in the wild" http://v2.rourkery.com

Comment: No prob. Feel free to post another question, but simply said yes. You could just `insert()` the whole flicker `<script>` tag into your `div` placeholder after the document loads with jQuery's `$(document).ready()`. It seems like a chicken before the egg thing, but it would work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could you just empty the `width` and `height` attributes?

```
$('.flickr_badge_image img').attr('width', '').attr('height', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".flickr_badge_image img").attr("height", "")
```

should work.